# Configure maintenance_template_path for 'capistrano-maintenace' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

In the `capistrano/maintenance` gem, I'm having trouble setting the path for the `:maintenance_template_path` variable.

I've tried

```
# Set the maintenance file path
set :maintenance_template_path, '/views/errors/maintenance'
set :maintenance_template_path, '/errors/maintenance'
set :maintenance_template_path, '/app/views/errors/maintenance'
set :maintenance_template_path, '/errors/maintenance.erb.html'
set :maintenance_template_path, '/views/errors/maintenance.erb.html'
set :maintenance_template_path, 'app/views/errors/maintenance.erb.html'
```

I keep getting `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen` error.

The file is in the correct spot `/Users/David/Documents/Development/myRailsApp/app/views/errors/maintenance.erb.html`

What is the correct configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires an absolute path. Assuming you are using `config/deploy.rb`, then you could do this:

```
set :maintenance_template_path, 
    File.expand_path("../../app/views/errors/maintenance.erb.html", __FILE__)
```